# How to get the WebView object inside a custom WebViewClient?

Tags: android, android-webview

I created a new function in a `CustomWebViewClient` class that needs to use the `webViewObject`. However, I dont seem to find a way how to access it without passing the parameter to the constructor.

This is what the class looks like:

```java
public class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    public CustomWebViewClient(){
           myFunction(); 
    }

    private myFunction(){
        //needs to use the webView object
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String check_url){
        //some code here
        return false
    }

}
```

This is how to set the custom class to a `webViewObject`:

```
CustomWebViewClient myWebViewClient = new CustomWebViewClient();
webViewObject.setWebViewClient(myWebViewClient);
```

Notice that `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` function gets the parameter. So its possible its there somewhere.

Comment: "I dont seem to find a way how to access it without passing the parameter to the constructor" -- so... pass the parameter to the constructor. Or, add a setter method to the `WebViewClient`. You make it sound like the constructor option is a problem -- if so, what specifically is the problem?

Comment: Yes, i also made a setter, it works well, the problem is its redundant because we were able to set the `myWebViewClient` for `webViewObject`. So its possible its there somewhere.